# Best approach to query a database to create a collection of a custom class in C++

Tags: c++, oop, orm, ado.net

I am new to interfaces with databases through c++ and was wondering what is the best approach to do the following:

I have an object with member variables that I define ahead of time, and member variables that I need to pull from a database given the known variables.  For example:

```cpp
class DataObject
{
public:
    int input1;
    string input2;
    double output1;

    DataObject(int Input1, string Input2) :
        input1(Input1), input2(Input2)
    {
        output1 = Initializer(input1,input2);
    }

private:
    Initializer(int, string);
    static RecordSet rs; //I am just guessing the object would be called RecordSet
}
```

Now, I can do something like:

```cpp
std::vector<DataObject> v;
for (int n = 0; n <= 10; ++n)
    for (char w = 'a'; w <= 'z'; ++w)
        v.push_back(DataObject{n,z});
```

And get an initialized vector of DataObjects.  Behind the scenes, Initializer will check check if rs already has data.  If not, it will connect to the database and query something like: `select input1, input2, output1 from ... where input1 between 1 and 10 and input 2 between 'a' and 'z'`, and then start initializing each `DataObject` with `output1` given each pair of `input1` and `input2`.

This would be utterly simple in C#, but from code samples I have found online it looks utterly ugly in C++.  I am stuck on two things.  As stated earlier, I am completely new to database interfaces in C++, and there are so many methods from which to choose, but I would like to hone in on a specific method that truly fits my purpose.  Furthermore - and this is the purpose - I am trying to make use of a static data set to pull data in a single query, rather than run a new query for each input1/input2 combination; even better yet, is there a way to have database results written directly into the newly created `DataObject`s rather than making a pit stop in some temporary RecordSet object.

To summarize and clarify: I have database on a relational database, and I am trying to pull the data and store it into a collection of objects.  How do I do this?  Any tips/direction - I am much obliged.

**EDIT 8/16/17: After some research and trials I have come up with the below**

So I've had progress by using an `ADORecordset` with the `put_CursorLocation` set to `adUseServer`:

```cpp
rs->put_CursorLocation(adUseServer)
```

My understanding is that by using this setting the query result is stored on the server, and the client side only gets the current row pointed to by `rs`.

So I get my data from the row and create the DataObject on the spot, emplace_back it into the vector, and finally call `rs->MoveNext()` to get the next row and repeat until I reach the end. Partial example as follows:

```cpp
std::vector<DataObject> v;
DataObject::rs.Open(connString,Sql); // Connection for wrapper class

for (int n = 0; n <= 10; ++n)
    for (char w = 'a'; w <= 'z'; ++w)
        v.emplace_back(DataObject{n,z});

// Somewhere else...
void DataObject::Initializer(int a, string b) {
    int ra; string rb; double rc;
    // For simplicity's sake, let's assume the result set is ordered
    //  in the same way as the for-loop, and that no data is missing.
    //  So the below sanity-check would be unnecessary, but included.
    while (!rs.IsEOF())
    {
        // Let's assume I defined these 'Get' functions
        ra = rs.Get<int>("Input1");
        rb = rs.Get<string>("Input2");
        rc = rs.Get<double>("Output1");
        rs.MoveNext();
        if (ra == a && rb == b) break;
    }
    return rc;
}

// Constructor for RecordSet:
RecordSet::RecordSet()
{
    HRESULT hr = rs_.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CADORecordset);
    ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED(hr);
    rs_->put_CursorLocation(adUseServer);
}
```

Now I'm hoping that I interpreted how this works correctly; otherwise, this would be a whole lot of fuss over nothing. I am not an ADO or .Net expert - clearly - but I'm hoping someone can chime in to confirm that this is indeed how this works, and perhaps shed some more light on the topic. On my end, I tested the memory usage using VS2015's diagnostic tool, and the heap seems to be significantly larger when using `adUseClient`. If my conjecture is correct, then why would anyone opt to use `adUseClient`, or any of the other choices, over `adUseServer`.

Comment: `char w = "a"` should be `char w = 'a'`. and it is not guaranty/portable to expect that `'a' + 25` is `'z'`

Comment: If your are looking for a library, it is off topic on SO.

Comment: If you are really into OOP, you may want to research Object Oriented database, rather than using a relational database.

Comment: @Jarod42, thanks, I corrected the double quotes to single quotes.  The code runs - I tested it before I put up the question.  The only part that is missing is how to initialize output1.  What do you mean by SO? Shared objects?  Can you provide more input?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, unfortunately, I have to pull the data from a relational database.  That is a constraint here.

Comment: SO for stackOverflow.com, this site.

Answer (score 0):

I think of two options:  by member type and BLOB.

For classes, I recommend one row per class instance with one column per member.  Search the supported data types by your database.  There are some common types.

Another method is to use the BLOB (Binary Large OBject) data type.  This is a "binary" data type used for storing data-as-is.

You can use the BLOB type for members that are of unsupported data types.

You can get more complicated by researching "Database Normalization" or "Database normal forms".